# Type error in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, nonetype

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\meanshift.py", line 15, in <module>
    roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Please help me to resolve this error, I am trying to make a region of interest on the first frame to track an object.

Comment: Probably `frame` is `None`. Please provide a little more code, to know how that is.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I get this kind of errors if I forgot to put a return statement at the end of a function:

```
def create_array(n):
    a = np.array((n,5))

b = create_array(10)
print b[5,1]
```

Without an explicit `return a` at the end of the function, it will return `None`.